# How to get consecutive elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Please look through the following code snippet -

HTML

```
<div class="aclass">
   <h1>This is heading one</h1>
   <p>This is paragraph one, this will be hidden automatically</p>
   <p>This is paragraph two, this will be hidden automatically</p>
   <p>This is paragraph three, this will be hidden automatically</p>
   <h1>This is heading two</h1>
   <p>This is paragraph four, this will be hidden automatically</p>
   <p>This is paragraph five, this will be hidden automatically</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aclass p {display:none;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.aclass h1').click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').toggle();
    });
});
```

This JS code toggles the display of a single p tag after the h1 tag when clicked on the h1 tag. But I need to toggle the display of consecutive p tags (one to three when clicked on heading one)

What should be the jQuery code to do so?

Comment: You should wrap your paragraphs in a div, and toggle that instead. Not that what you are asking is not possible, but it would be more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I played the fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hMsXz/2/

here the code for saving clicks:

```
 $('.aclass h1').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h1','p').toggle();
 });
```

Comment: Can you add the code to your answer?  Also, `$(this).andSelf()` does nothing, it adds `this` to the collection (which already contains `this`).

Comment: yeah, i had forgotten that from an 'experiment', edited already

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$('.aclass h1').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h1', 'p').toggle(); // Selects all p tags after the h1
                                           // stops when it hits an h1
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dt7LH/

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your meaning is to expand/collapse all `<p>` tags below the click `<h1>`?

Use `nextUntil('h1')` to select all sibling elements up to the `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.nextUntil` introduced in jQuery 1.4

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.aclass h1').click(function(){
       $(this).nextUntil('h1').toggle();
   });
});
```